# PHP and SQL timezone off

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to fetch data from MySQL database using PHP and everything works fine aside from the date. The date is over a day behind and I just can't figure out how to fix it. I'm using PHPMyAdmin with Apache on my CentOS 8 server PC.

The date-column on the database has type: **datetime** with default value: **current_timestamp()**.

I'm using PHP to insert the values onto my database except for the date-column which I was hoping the database would sort out by itself.

I understand I could either try and change the timezone on MySQL (I couldn't find a way to make this work as the query didn't seem to recognize Europe/Helsinki timezone) or I could just change it on PHP side before it gets displayed on the website but no luck there either.

Code used to fetch the date: (+ some different time echos)

```php
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
  while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $currdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
  }
  echo $currdate;
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  echo $date;
  $newdate = new DateTime($currdate, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Helsinki'));
  echo $newdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  $timestamp = date('H:i d.m.Y', strtotime($rows['date']));
```

They all print out the same date and time which is

> 2020-12-06 18:41:53

The current time (as of writing this) should be 2020-12-07 20:04:00 which is over a day behind. And when I try a different timezone like Europe/Paris, the time won't change at all.

The database currently has some example data so I can delete all records without a problem if it was needed to create a new table with a different default value. Or I could try to insert the date value manually from the PHP script but the problem would still persist as PHP has the timezone all wrong.

I have no idea where the issue is. I'm somewhat new to this stuff but I have looked this up and tried many different ways I found from here and other sites but no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that your server's clock is correct. (or make sure that NTP service is enabled so that it will sync the clock).

On the server level , you may wish to make sure that your server timezone is set correctly.

Assuming you are using a linux server, to change the time zone in Linux systems use the sudo timedatectl set-timezone command followed by the long name of the time zone you want to set.

On the PHP side, you may use date_default_timezone_set to set the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script

Comment: I think the issue was on the server timezone. I've been using cli so I didn't even realise the timezone was so off. That fixed the issue. Thank you!